# Default checkbox state: checked or unchecked?

Tags: user-interface, design-patterns

I have an application settings page with a bunch of checkboxes. How should I choose the default checked state of the checkboxes?

I see the following options:

1. Always set the default state to unchecked, but this leads to negative statements in the checkbox text (like "Don't automatically show due schedules"), which is sometimes hard to understand.
2. Always phrase the checkbox text to have a positive meaning (like "Automatically show due schedules"), but this leads to inconsistent default checkbox states, both checked and unchecked.
3. ... any other options?

Any guidelines, best-practices, advices for this problem?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

These are my "rules" for this:

- Make all statements "positive" so 'Automatically show due schedules' rather than 'Dont automatically show due schedules'
- Make the default configuration whatever it needs to be for the majority use case, even if it looks like you've scattered ticks and non-ticks across your configuration screen
- Group related settings together, be it with "fieldset"/"group" elements or tabs
- Use the best UI element for the job. For example: Tri-state check boxes aren't particularly intuitive and providing a drop-down or set of three radio buttons is more approchable for those less technically inclined

So - Option 2 from your list =)

Answer (score 9):

Definitely Number 2. Checkboxes should always have positive meaning. If this means some of your defaults are checks and some are not then that's not a problem in my opinion.

Answer (score 8):

I'd choose 2. I see no reason why all checkboxes should be unchecked by default. Choose the state that the user most likely wants (or that causes least damage) and a text that is easiest to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would store the default state along with your text. Unfortunately [some people](http://www.spamcop.net/reported.shtml) are [very picky](http://www.out-law.com/page-5657) about what is opting out vs optin in, so there is no easy way to have readable text and things being set only one way by default.

Also if there is no default it makes the users actually read what they are getting into or out of.

Answer (score 1):

All I would add to the other answers, is if you want to ensure the user makes a choice instead of accepting a default chosen by you, use a pair of radio buttons (neither one selected) and require them to select one before proceeding.

I should note this is a radical approach and I would only use it when there is a critical option that the user needs to consider carefully before choosing.

Comment: I would argue against this. A radio button group should IMHO always have a default selection.